# Can you lose privileges with loss of rep?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Suppose your rep is just over the borderline of a new privilege (eg. reviewing the edit queue), and you get downvoted, or downvote something yourself.

If the loss of rep brings you under the privilege requirement, do you lose the privilege?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

[Can you lose an ability if your reputation falls below a threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold)

I actually experienced it myself. Some guy serial-upvoted me past the 10,000 threshold (note: nobody asked him to do so). I could then see the deleted posts. He did it just for fun, so then he cancelled his upvotes, and I was unable to see those posts again (until I regained the rep more "legally").

Comment: Thanks. Sounds frustrating. I have terrible luck with SE’s search engine. How did you find the link?

Comment: Google: "meta stackexchange lose privilege loss of reputation". These kind of questions all have an answer on the main meta. But the search engine from stackexchange often returns irrelevant results, so when I search for something on SE, I ask Google, giving the name of the site first. Yeah, it's a shame, but who can beat Google, anyway?

Comment: Ok, good tip. I often have more success finding what I need through the “Questions that may already have your answer” pop-up that appears when you enter the title of a new question, than I do with the SE search engine. So, usually I’ll just start typing question explicitly for the pop-up. I’ll try your tip next time.

Comment: A legitimate way of having the same thing happen is through making bounties